# Can't save customer in CE 1.9 without providing current admin password

Tags: admin, customer, ce-1.9.1.0

It seems like since upgrading to CE 1.9.1.0 I'm not able to modify **any** customer information without proving my current administrator password.

Surely this should only be required when trying to change the customer password or something along those lines?

Is this how it should behave??

**Edit - JS Error on page load:**

The error reads as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
>
> (anonymous function) @ (index):1189

Which refers to:

```
$$('#_accountnew_password,#account-send-pass').each(function(elem) {
    $(elem).on('change', function() {
```

Comment: do you get a js warning or the call to the server returns the message?

Comment: I didn't even bother to look at that, doh! Updated question. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't made any customizations to the customer page, no. Weird.

Comment: Hmmm.. this doesn't look like core code to me. Do you have an extension that affects the customer admin section? Maybe `$(elem)`  should be `jQuery(elem)`. Just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: Thanks. Going to dig further into it, you've helped a lot. Will report back ASAP.

Comment: This is default behavior. To edit customer password magento ask current admin password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the field "Current admin password" only appears as soon as you focus on "New password" and enter something there, or check the "Send generated password" checkbox. If this fails because of previous JS errors, the field is always visible and unfortunately set to "required".

The script comes from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Renderer_Adminpass` (so it is core JS, and no extension as suspected) and it's exactly the script that is responsible for toggling the admin password input, as you can see in the following lines:

```
        if ($('_accountnew_password').getValue() || $('account-send-pass').checked) {
            $('{$element->getHtmlId()}_container').show();
            $('{$element->getHtmlId()}').enable();
        } else {
            $('{$element->getHtmlId()}_container').hide();
            $('{$element->getHtmlId()}').disable();
        }
```

This *should work*. If you don't have a custom admin theme, the problem must be in some extension. The message only makes sense to me if an extension adds jQuery to the admin area, but without the `jquery.noConflict()` mode. Then, `$` is the jQuery object and Magento's scripts which expect it to be prototypejs fail.